# How to enable button if all divs are selected in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have some divs generated dynamically. Once all the divs are selected submit button has to be enabled, can someone please help me?

```js
let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let allSelected = document.querySelectorAll('selected');
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  card[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('selected');
  })
}
```

```css
.card.selected{
background: #0173fb;
}
```

```html
<section class='container'>
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="cardItm">
      <div class="card">
        card items
      </div>
      
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class='btn'>Submit</button>
</section>
```

```
let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let allSelected = document.querySelectorAll('selected');
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  card[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('selected');
  })
}
```

In this code I am adding 'selected' class for the div onclick. I want this in pure javascript.. no jquery or any other library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please shar emore details. What do you mean by "selected" divs? Can you share more code such that others could reproduce your situation?

Comment: Your snippet seems to be lacking the HTML so cannot work for us, could you add it, thanks.

Comment: Please, add HTML to your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the available divs with the selected divs and enable the button if it matches.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    div{
      height: 10px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .selected{
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  
  <button class="btn" disabled>Click</button>
  
  <script>
let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  card[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
    // add seclected class to clicke div
    e.target.classList.add('selected');
    
    // get all selected/clicked divs
    let allSelected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
    
    // compare available divs with selected divs
    if(card.length === allSelected.length){
      console.log("Enable button", btn[0])
      
      btn[0].onclick = () => {
        alert("Button clicked");
      };
      
      // enable button
      btn[0].disabled = false;
      
    }
    
  });
}    
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Troubleshooting (https://github.com/Bhanumathi-a/cards)

Your problem with your code is that you add the "selected" class on sub elements too! `` When you add a console log on the event handler you see that there are other elements than the divs get selected which gives you the filled array that matches the length of the available divs:

[image]

You can clearly see that the array contains more elements than only divs.
To fix this, find the nearest `div.card` element from the clicked children:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Member FDIC</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 360px;
}

header {
    display: block;
}

a.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #0173fb;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

.loanDetails {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    display: flex;
}

.cardBlk {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cardItm {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media(min-width:1240px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
    .cardItm {
        width: 24%;
    }
}

@media(min-width:1920px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1820px;
    }
    .cardItm {
        width: 33%;
    }
}

.card {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #2a2b2d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px 15px 30px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card .info, .card .checked {
    height: 39px;
    width: 39px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .info {
    background: url(assets/exclamation.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.card .checked {
    background: url(assets/checked\ active.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.card img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 50px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}

.card.selected, .card:hover {
    background: #0173fb;
    color: #fff;
}

.card:hover .info, .card.selected .info {
    background-image: url(assets/exclamation\ white.png);
}

.card:hover .checked, .card.selected .checked {
    background-image: url(assets/checked\ inactive.png);
}

.btnBlk {
    text-align: center;
    display: block
}

.btn {
    background: #0173fb;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #0173fb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn:disabled {
    background: #9ac5fb;
    border-color: #9ac5fb;
    cursor: default;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
            <!-- <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Welcome, John Doe</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav> -->
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <header class="loanDetails">
            <div class="container">
                loan
                <progress value="30" max="100" id=progress>30%</progress>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section class='container'>
            <ul class="cards">
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card 1">
                        <span class="checked"></span>
                        <img src="assets/location.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(100% completed)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card 2">
                        <span class="info"></span>
                        <img src="assets/property.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(Not Started)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <span class="info"></span>
                        <img src="assets/income.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(Not Started)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <span class="checked"></span>
                        <img src="assets/assets.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(50% completed)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <span class="checked"></span>
                        <img src="assets/real estate.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(70% completed)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <span class="info"></span>
                        <img src="assets/declarations.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(90% completed)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cardItm">
                    <div class="card">
                        <span class="checked"></span>
                        <img src="assets/e-concent.png" alt="">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Get started</h2>
                            <span>(Not Started)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btnBlk">
                <button class="btn" id="submitBtn" disabled>Submit Application</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script>

        let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
        let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
        let progress = document.getElementById('progress');

        for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
            card[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {

                let closest = e.target.closest("div.card");
                closest.classList.add('selected');

                progress.value = progress.value + 10;

                let allSelected = document.querySelectorAll('div.selected');

                if (card.length === allSelected.length) {

                    btn[0].onclick = () => {
                        console.log('clicked');
                    };

                    btn[0].disabled = false;
                }


            });
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Marc, but button got enabled before last div (-1 div), I have I 7 divs but button got enabled on 6th button click

Comment: What ? im sorry, i cant understand that. For me, in firefox, you have to click all on all divs to enable the button. do you want that you have only to select one less ?

Comment: No, It is selecting one less now.. not after all div clicked. I want to enable after all divs are selected. I am checking chrome

Comment: Sorry, i cant reproduce the issue. tested on firefox, chromium on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64, firefox Windows Server 2019, Firefox, Windows 10

Comment: https://github.com/Bhanumathi-a/cards I have added all my files here. Please check

Answer (score 0):

try like this. Pure javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
});

    let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
    let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
      card[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
        if(card.length === document.getElementsByClassName('selected').length){
            btn[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        else{
        btn[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
        }
      })
    }
```

```css
.card{
padding: 8px;
border: 1px solid #eee;
cursor: pointer;
}
ul, li{
    list-style: none;
}

.card.selected{
background-color: rgb(155,155,155);
}

.btn{
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class='container'>
   <ul class="cards">
       <li class="cardItm">
           <div class="card">
               card items 1
           </div>
          <div class="card">
              card items 2
          </div>
          <div class="card">
              card items 3
          </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <button class='btn'>Submit</button>
   </section>

</body>
```

Or you can add eventListener without for. Like below:

```
let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('card')){
        e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
        if(card.length === document.getElementsByClassName('selected').length){
            btn[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        else{
            btn[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: In both solutions if we click any div twice by mistake, before all div selected button is getting enabled.

Comment: So what do you mean? I didnt understand @Bhanumathi-a

Comment: @Bhanumathi-a what browser are you using for testing ?! Thats not possible. you add a class to a clicked div, and count how many divs are have the added class. if you click a div 2,3,4,5 times you dont add the class "selected" to any other div. See my solution and add your code snippet with the issue to verify

Comment: i just added `toggle` for more flexible example. You should use it just `add`

Comment: github.com/Bhanumathi-a/cards I have added all my files here. Please check

Comment: https://github.com/AnyOneorSomeOne/ForBhanumathi-a @Bhanumathi-a